# Vue not loading data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript, vue.js

I have a vue/coffeescript app that looks like this:

There are no errors in the console, and it says it's making a successful external request for the JSON, however When I say `{{book.name}}`, it only returns as Test instead of coming from the JSON.

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
  showModal: false,
  book: {
    name: "Test",
    description: "",
    photo: ""
  }
}

ready: () ->
  this.getBookData()
  console.log (this.book)

methods: {
  getBookData: () ->
    self = $(this)
    $.getJSON 'GGPK4A.json', (data) ->
      self.book = data
}

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in coffeescript, but I think the issue is that `this` doesn't refer to Vue within the callback function, so setting `this.book` isn't working.  Normally you can fix this using `.bind(this)` on the function, or setting `var vm = this` before the ajax call and setting `vm.book` in the callback.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already tried to do this (setting `that = this` outside of the ajax function), but it doesn't seem to change the situation?

Comment: Ah, but you are calling `console.log()` immediately after sending the http request, not waiting for the book to come back. try logging the book in the callback function, it should be correct.

Comment: it is correct when I log it in the callback function, my issue is that `{{book.name}}` doesn't update once the ajax request is done.

Comment: it still doesn't update? The value is still display as "Test", the default. When I console.log(this.book) however, it shows the JSON its supposed to be showing

Comment: Ah ok sorry I think I've got it... try `self.$set('book', data)`. Vue's reactive capabilities are bound to the original `book` object, so when you replace it you're circumventing the listeners

Comment: I just figured it out, that was stupid of me. I used `{{ $data | json }}` to debug and realized `{{ book.name }}` didn't work because the JSON had two nested books, so the correct way to retrieve it was {{ book.book.name }}. Thanks for your help!